# Reference request: explicit equivariant localization formula on toric complete intersections

Tags: sg.symplectic-geometry, gromov-witten-theory, equivariant-cohomology

This post is about an equivariant integration formula in a famous paper https://arxiv.org/pdf/alg-geom/9701016.pdf by Alexander Givental, where the author presented the formula without proof or reference. It turns equivariant localization into calculation of residues. I am trying to combine it with global residue theorem to derive some vanishing result of some invariant. The equation is as follows (It can be found at the bottom of page 22 of the paper):

$$
\int_X f(p,\lambda)=\sum_{\alpha}Res_{\alpha}\frac{f(p,\lambda)dp_1\wedge\cdots\wedge dp_k}{u_1(p,\lambda)\cdots u_n(p,\lambda)}
$$
where $X$ is a toric symplectic variety $f(p,\lambda)$ is an equivariant form, $p_k$ forms base of $H^2(X)$ (the Picard group) and $u_i(p,\lambda)=\sum_ip_im_{ij}-\lambda_j$, where $m_{ij}$ is an integer matrix  describing how $p_i$ span all the invariant divisors and $\lambda_i$ is the ordinary equivariant index for torus action. The RHS sums over fixed point or pole specified by  some of the $u_i=0$.

This paper is hard to read because I am not an expert on symplectic geometry but I really need to re-derive this explicit formula. Maybe some experts could kindly provide me some hints or references and any other discussion is welcomed. Thanks in advance.